# What does BSS not found error means in Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-driver, ifconfig, 802.11n

I have a yocto linux distribution and installed the rtl8723bu linux driver for the usb dongle.
After plugging the usb i am getting some logs and also this log below..

> [ 1985.355372] RTL871X: rtw_cfg80211_indicate_connect(wlan0) BSS not
> found !!

I am not able to understand what does that log means? and is it something important?
or should i just ignore it?

Comment: My research indicates it's likely caused by a driver issue.

Comment: Do you know what problem can it create?  because my connection is stable and runing without any problem.

Comment: It can create the message you are asking about.

Comment: well, thats really helpfu. Please post it as an answer ;)

Comment: I don't have a solution to the problem, so I will refrain, from submitting an incomplete answer.